# Google js api different marker image for each marker dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using he following js for adding google map, which pulls all my locations from my database within the foreach loop, I want each markers to have a different icon which will be stores in a by field.

Lets say for example I have a field called filename which will store the image path/name (icon.jpg).

I was wondering how I can adapt this script written by August Li to do that.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            //Sample code written by August Li
            var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
                       new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                       new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
            var center = null;
            var map = null;
            var currentPopup;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
                var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                bounds.extend(pt);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pt,
                    icon: icon,
                    map: map
                });
                var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: info,
                    maxWidth: 300
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    if (currentPopup != null) {
                        currentPopup.close();
                        currentPopup = null;
                    }
                    popup.open(map, marker);
                    currentPopup = popup;
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                    map.panTo(center);
                    currentPopup = null;
                });
            }           
            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                    zoom: 14,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                    },
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
                    }
                });
<?php

foreach ($dataProvider->models as $model) {
    echo "addMarker({$model->lat}, {$model->lon}, '<b>$model->name</b><br />$model->website');";
}

?>
 center = bounds.getCenter();
     map.fitBounds(bounds);

     }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You would just need a function like:

```
function makeIcon(filename) {
    return new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                   "http://example.com/path/to/icons/" + filename,
                   new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                   new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
               );
}
```

updated of course with the path to the location of your icon files.

Then you would need to update the addMarker function to accept an icon parameter:

```
        function addMarker(lat, lng, gicon, info) {
            var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            bounds.extend(pt);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pt,
                icon: gicon,
                map: map
            });
            ...
```

Then in your PHP loop, you would need to add the makeIcon() call separately. So, for example,

```
<?php
foreach ($dataProvider->models as $model) {
    echo "gicon = makeIcon(your filename);";
    echo "addMarker({$model->lat}, {$model->lon}, gicon, '<b>$model->name</b><br />$model->website');";
}
?>
```

This echos the code to get the gIcon object based on your filename and then passes it to the modified addMarker.

Comment: Thanks I'll try again however when I used addmarker(lat, lon, filename, info) the map still displayed however the marker's weren't being added however I'll give it another go just wondering if there was anything wrong I was doing when echoing the marker within my for each loop.

Comment: I tried the following  `echo "addMarker({$model->lat}, {$model->lon}, mapicon.jpg, '<b>$model->name</b><br />$model->website');";` but it only echoed the mapicon.jpg not http://example/com/path/to/icons/mapicon.jpg

Comment: The original answer was based on a Javascript approach. I modified to answer to take into account the fact that you are generating the Javascript code in a PHP loop.

Comment: How do I call the variable gicon and execute the js function within the for each loop as it is currently just echoing it as a sting so it just says gicon in my source code.

Comment: The PHP loop is echoing Javascript code in the middle of a bunch of other JS, so it's really just dynamically creating JS code that you then need to send to the browser.

Comment: I have tried to implement your code/example and it outputs the following `gicon = makeIcon(blue.png);addMarker(51.512944, -0.133896, gicon, '<b>Supreme</b><br />http://someurl.com');` rather than `gicon = makeIcon(blue.png);addMarker(51.512944, -0.133896, (http://example.com/pathtoimage/blue.png, '<b>Supreme</b><br />http://someurl.com');` which is why I don't think the makeIcon function can be executing.

Comment: makeIcon is a javascript function that creates a Javascript object, namely a gIcon object. This object is what is passed to the new google.maps.Marker statement, not a string.